# Windows server 2008: automatically copying outlook configuration for all users?

Tags: windows-server-2008, outlook-2007

I have a windows server 2008 with aprox. 100 users.

They all use a software that requires an account configured at outlook to send emails.

I am trying to configure their outlook account automatically. Note that they all use the same SMTP/POP account for this software.

I tried to use prf files, but they don't work for me as it is still necessary for user to type his password.

Is there a way to configure outlook at one account and them copy configuration automatically for all users?

Thanks.

Comment: I've voted you up. If you figure this out, I want to know the answer as well!

Comment: How would that be possible when every user has a unique username and password? I think using the prf files are your best option.

Comment: Maybe i did not make it clear, but users will all use the same account. In other words, same smtp username/password.